# Flexible text retrieval with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I've a bunch of HTML text streams, each containing the phrase "Toy:" once.

E.g.,

```
<p><b>Toy: </b><b>Train</b></p>
<p><b>Toy:</b><b>Chess game</b></p>
<p><b>Toy: </b><span>Guitar</span></p>
<p><b>Toy: </b>Doll</p>
<p><strong><ul>Toy: </ul></strong></b><b>Monkey costume</b></p>
<p><b>Toy: Train</b></p>
<p>Toy: Skipping rope</p>
<p>Toy:Snail</p>
```

I'd like to pull out the text from these.

e.g.,

```
Toy: Train
Toy:Chess game
Toy: Guitar
Toy: Doll
Toy: Monkey costume
Toy: Train
Toy: Skipping rope
Toy:Snail
```

I'm having trouble getting to a single xpath expression which I feel should be possible.

Example:

```
//p[starts-with(descendant-or-self::*/text(), "%s")]
```

Comment: It's not clear what language/program you are using to get the elements for this xpath. For example, it's trivial to get this result with xquery, by using `data(//p)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, XPath requires well-formed XML:

```
<root>
  <p><b>Toy: </b><b>Train</b></p>
  <p><b>Toy:</b><b>Chess game</b></p>
  <p><b>Toy: </b><span>Guitar</span></p>
  <p><b>Toy: </b>Doll</p>
  <p><strong><ul>Toy: </ul></strong><b>Monkey costume</b></p>
  <p><b>Toy: Train</b></p>
  <p>Toy: Skipping rope</p>
  <p>Toy:Snail</p>
</root>
```

Then, you can select all of the `p` elements that start with `Toy:`:

```
//p[starts-with(., 'Toy:')]
```

> I'd like to pull out the text from these.

In pure **XPath 1.0**, you can do

```
//p[starts-with(., 'Toy:')]//text()
```

to retrieve the text nodes under the `p` element starting with `Toy:`, but each text node string will be on its own line rather than grouped per enclosing `p`.

To keep the text grouped under each enclosing `p`, you can step through the selected `p` elements and get the string value of each element using whatever hosting language you're using to evaluate the XPath, or you could use **XPath 2.0**:

```
//p[starts-with(., 'Toy:')]/string()
```

will return

```
Toy: Train
Toy:Chess game
Toy: Guitar
Toy: Doll
Toy: Train
Toy: Skipping rope
Toy:Snail
```

Comment: thanks @kjhughes - I was misdirected in trying to specify siblings, parents and descents. this is a far cleaner approach.